# Storing custom data in Alexa devices

Tags: account, alexa-skills-kit

I want to store some custom values in the Alexa devices, so that, from next time I need to get these values in the request.

Example scenario:
I'll store the customer id in the device, from the request JSON if I get that customer ID, I can get the relevant information for the customer. I am not satisfied with the LINK ACCOUNT features for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot store any data in the device as Alexa is not designed to store any data.

You can store data in DynamoDB if you want to keep data in AWS itself. Write a logic inside your Alexa execution logic to save data to DynamoDB. If you want to keep data outside AWS then expose a REST endpoint and connect it from the code you have written for Alexa execution.